# Multiple Application in same Firebase Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a project that has two applications. A user app and an admin app. Both apps should use the same database, which can easily be done in firebase. Now I want to build an Authentication for both apps. But if you register in one app (eg. user app) you should not have an account in the admin app. So I don't know how to handle this problem in Firebase because all apps in one project build on the same Authentication-System.
What is the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "both apps should use the same database", you need to use the same project for authentication.

One of the classical ways in this case is to use a **role-based access control** strategy. Admin users would have a specific "Admin" role and only users with this role can read/write Admin data.

**Custom Claims** are the way to implement such role-based access control in Firebase. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) explains it very well (including how to use the custom claims in Firebase security rules -to restrict access to data based on these claims- as well as how to use them to hide/show  elements of your application user interface depending on the role).

You may also be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e), which shows how to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740699/flutter-firebase-admin-features-in-app-or-cloud-functions/59741087#59741087) may also interest you, in particular the answers to the last two OP questions ("Can I build an Admin Panel inside the client app?" and "Should I build an Admin Panel in another app and using Cloud Functions?")